# MPG123 library: function mpg123_encsize not found

Tags: c

This is my very first experience with the MPG123 library, and I'm a bit confused.
I found a small example about using this library, with libao, but when i try to compile I got an error.

This is the example code "Play local files": http://hzqtc.github.io/2012/05/play-mp3-with-libmpg123-and-libao.html

I compile with: `gcc -O2 -o play play.c -lmpg123 -lao`

The error I get is:

```
/tmp/ccmEoxBp.o: In function `main':
play.c:(.text.startup+0x8d): undefined reference to `mpg123_encsize'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Find `libmpg123.a` and see if it contains the symbol: `nm libmpg123.a | fgrep mpg123_encsize`.

Comment: My bad, I have to develop a small C++ project with this library. Anyway, this example is C-related.

Comment: @user2707994 As to the question, it seems that the library [doesn't indeed contain this function](https://github.com/gypified/libmpg123/search?q=mpg123_encsize&ref=cmdform).

Comment: Try ldconfig -v | grep libmpg123, you probably have an old version of the library. encsize  was only added in 0.26.6, mine is 0.36.6 and it works.

Comment: Yes, also in the compiled library i can't find the symbol. According to the official documentation, this is a function which is still used, documented and mantained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an old version of the mp123 library, according to the release notes it was added in 26.0.26
https://github.com/gypified/libmpg123/blob/master/NEWS.libmpg123

> 26.0.26
>   - Added mpg123_encsize().
>   - Added flag MPG123_SKIP_ID3V2.